# Call ActivityB's function without creating intent? Android

Tags: android, class, object, android-intent, android-activity

How can we call a function of an activity from another activity without using intent in android?

Comment: Is the activity whose function is to be called present in the Activity Stack already?

Comment: please edit your question to include function in activityB

Comment: you can do it creating object of activityB and access the function through that object

Comment: You could say: "Close, Sesame!"

Answer (score 0):

make the function/method public and static, then you can refer to it by classname.method()

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ActivityA_layout);
        ActivityB.functionInActivityB(); // Calling function defined in ActivityB
    }
}

public class ActivityB extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ActivityB_layout);
    }

    public static void functionInActivityB(){
        // Things To Be Done In ActivityB
    }
}
```

Comment: providing an example would be beneficial in an answer